# PostgreSQL function is always called inside a transaction

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying to research if postgres functions are always run as a single transaction and have found hints in various answers but no links back to the official documentation.  Can somebody cite a source that states postgres functions are always run inside a single transaction?

Have read through the documentation here but no luck: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-transactions.html

The functions are just being called via a select call and no transaction BEGIN/COMMIT calls are used:

```
select ccdb.fn_automation_for_updation()
```

In short I am going through a code base where a user is trying to solve concurrency issues inside a function but think a race condition is present.

Comment: Functions are always part of the transaction of the caller.

Answer (score 3):

In the [documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html) it says:

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it.

In other words, even a single `SELECT` happens inside a transaction even if no specific `BEGIN` command was issued.

Functions that are called from a query will execute in the context of the transaction established by the query.

Procedures executed using `CALL` or `DO` do not automatically execute in a transaction; procedures should manage their own transactions. See: [plpgsql transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html).